# Issue regarding bottom margin on img tag

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to create some space between the profile picture and the text, but when I applied bottom margin to the image, it doesn't work. I tried setting `display: block`, but it makes no difference. Why is this not working?

When I change the `height` and `width` of the `#profile-pic` to `100%`, or when I add margin to the `#profile-pic` directly, it works, but I don't understand why its not working in the following case?

```css
#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#profile-pic {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

#profile-pic img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 38%;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div id="profile-pic">
    <img src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/322027365/original.jpg?t=1541703413" alt="profile pic">
  </div>
  <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum autem sequi, est enim, eligendi voluptas et ut aspernatur nostrum laboriosam maxime itaque assumenda sapiente reiciendis, tenetur exercitationem culpa quia ea laudantium! Exercitationem
    quo quibusdam, sit quas perspiciatis aspernatur aliquam enim nihil assumenda omnis sunt sequi rerum quisquam. Nesciunt,

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have a fixed height parent `#profile-pic` and your `img` element has 100% height so it will take as much as his parent space `250px` and margin will not affect it there just overflowing the other element with no real effect on the displayed image.

Answer (score 0):

Give it to your div instead of your image

```css
#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#profile-pic {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#profile-pic img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 38%;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div id="profile-pic">
    <img src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/322027365/original.jpg?t=1541703413" alt="profile pic">
  </div>
  <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum autem sequi, est enim, eligendi voluptas et ut aspernatur nostrum laboriosam maxime itaque assumenda sapiente reiciendis, tenetur exercitationem culpa quia ea laudantium! Exercitationem
    quo quibusdam, sit quas perspiciatis aspernatur aliquam enim nihil assumenda omnis sunt sequi rerum quisquam. Nesciunt,
</section>
```

Comment: its already mentioned in the post that giving to div is working, he/she is asking why not working for the img tag.

Comment: True I did not realize @SebMaz93